# Is there any way to have a repository made of files from two copied repos that continues to update from the two separate repositories on github?

Tags: git, github

I want to put together something from two github repos. Once I do so I want the files associated with their respective repos to update every time the two main repo updates. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It's possible to do; just ask your search engine. Thanks.

Comment: Google said Submodules: https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255, I don't know why I didn't find it before. Thank you.